# theme_field() not working in a module

Tags: 7

Writing in to custom.module:

```
function custom_field($variables) {
  dpm($variables)
}
```

Returns nothing is it working in a module? And i have devel installed and turned on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use that method to override a theme function in a *theme* (template.php).

To override the callback function for a theme using a module, you need to implement [`hook_theme_registry_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7), e.g.

```
function MYMODULE_theme_reigstry_alter(&$registry) {
  $registry['field']['function'] = 'MYMODULE_theme_field_override';
}
```

You might need to change other things too (file path, preprocess functions, process functions, etc, depends on your use case). The above method will help with all of that too.

Comment: Thanks, i've readed somewhere that i could use that in a module. Misinformed me. My goal is to override html of my image field that i use in a node (i don't want to place all the additional php code in node--content_type.tpl.php). What's the best approach to do that?

Comment: There are a few ways really...you can implement `hook_preprocess_node` and alter `$vars['content']['field_name']`, or implement `hook_node_view` and alter `$node->content['field_name']`. Or you could go all out and implement `hook_field_formatter_info` and describe a new formatter for the image field type, which you can choose to use through the manage display form